# How to get changeset tag from .osm file into PostGIS enabled Postgres db

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

End goal: visualize geographic data from .osm file with QGIS by adding PostGIS layers which include changeset information.

I have used osm2pgsql successfully to populate PostGIS and visualize the layers in QGIS but cannot bring in the changeset field.

I have used the --extra attributes function to bring in fields like osm_uid and osm_user but --extra attributes apparently does not allow you to bring in the changeset field.

How can I bring in the changeset field with osm2pgsql? Is there some alternative route I should take instead of osm2pgsql?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you can't do it with osm2pgsql.

You may:

- Use osmosis http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.44 but it uses different db schema, and there is no such thing as separate import of changesets into sole table.
- Do it yourself. It's actually quite easy to use SAX xml parser to get changesets and their tags. Just don't try to upload full dump into memory.

Answer (score -1):

You need one more step which is adding the values to your style file.

For details:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Import_style

Default Style file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/master/default.style

Comment: Could you share examples and more detail? Links can disappear!

Comment: osm2pgsq has only user, timestamp, and few more changesets' attributes, but no changesets' tags.